# PHP-EXCEL Library process memory / delay

Tags: php, excel, memory-management

Can i know please, of any solution exists and related to the delay and the allocate memory of the php-excel library from codeplex??? The problem is that when we want to export data to excel file using the php-excel library from codeplex , it's take too time and allocate memory to the fullest.

For use-case below:

- the RAM size is : 4G
- data contents 3500 records approximately

When we click to export data to excel file, the message below appears:

> Fatal error:Allowed memory size 10773741824 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 59 bytes...)

i have increase the allocate memory to 3G but the resource has been used to the max ... why this case?it's normal to take that? and to be happened?

Comment: i used : ini_set('memory_limit', '3072M'); but i dont know some problem happen although this instruction... the allocation memory is too large...and the delay of export also...

Comment: No! it isn't normal! How big are the records? Are you using PHPExcel caching? Are you reading every database record into PHP memory before storing them in PHPExcel? How long does it take?

Comment: i have disabled the php excel caching,  because i guess that take more time (i dont sure), the process is that i read the database record and than i store them in the phpExcel, that take too much time, it's not normal, i guess, look for an example: a data withe size 450KB needs a 19 seconds to be exported...any solutions exist to reduce the time of exporting and the allocation memory used???

Comment: Without knowing a lot more detail about exactly what you're doing in your code, it's almost impossible to suggest how performance/memory usage can be improved. Caching is a trade-off reducing memory usage, but at a cost in performance. We spend a lot of effort in PHPExcel trying to reduce both, but there are limits to what we can do. What is 450k though? Is this the size of the generated file? Number of worksheets/cells is a lot more important than size of the generated file.

Comment: yes the 450KB is Is this the size of the generated file viewed after export, the number worksheets/cells is in max case : 78 worksheets...

Comment: there are 4 existing tables with very much fields, the idea is that i want to export the data to excel file using codeignitor framework.After the join statement and reading the data from the database, i prepare that sheets and i put the read data into the cells using ->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($gmposputfstlign,$number,'$value'); at the end of the script, i prepare the header to view the excel file and i use the instructions below:$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel,'Excel5');
$objWriter->save('php://output');
$objPHPExcel->disconnectWorksheets(); 
unset($objPHPExcel);

Comment: If I'm to look at what's happening, kindly provide some of your code to help me... otherwise my guesses are likely to be completely wrong.

Comment: IF u can help me from other way, if u know a solution to speed the export option and to know why that take the resource of the max???thank you in advance.

Comment: the problem is in the resource allocation not in the programming...

Answer (score 0):

We can export data directly into the file saved for save memory and process, with text file that's too efficient , but in case for csv, excel file, should be take in count the format and the ability of library used do that issue.